# Optimisation SQL-query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help me optimise SQL query.

```
"SELECT
c.id,
c.parent_id,
c.name,
c.description,
c.url,
c.meta_title,
c.meta_keywords,
c.meta_description,
c.image,
c.visible,
c.position,
COUNT(u.id) as products_count
FROM __categories c
LEFT JOIN __users_categories uc ON uc.category_id=c.id 
LEFT JOIN __users u ON u.id=uc.user_id AND u.group_id=2 AND u.city_id=".$_SESSION['city_id']."
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.parent_id, c.position"
```

In DB-table __users_categories more than 17587 rows. Answer 200 of server have time 2140 ms. Without request in table __users_categories answer 200 of server have time 680ms. How doing in SQL-query request to table __users_categories with minimum time of answer 200 of server?

Comment: do you have proper indexes on your tables? do you have index on `__users_categories.category_id` and index on `__users_categories.user_id` ?

Comment: maybe also u.group_id and u.city_id

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: that's not actually a huge number of rows by modern standards. Probably indexes need improving. But without more info we can't say precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems ok.

Please make sure that you have indexes both on `__users_categories.category_id` and `__users_categories.user_id`.

With mysql, this should do the thing:

`CREATE INDEX user_categories_user_id ON __users_categories (user_id);`

`CREATE INDEX user_categories_category_id ON __users_categories (category_id);`

Also in case of this particular query you may want to put index one index on multiple columns

`CREATE INDEX name_this_index_accordingly ON __users (city_id, group_id,id);`